# Installing Atheros ar9845

Tags: wireless, 10.04

I'm trying to install atheros ar9845 with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (32-bit), what are my options to make it work.

I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-wireless-lucid-generic
```

Then after restarting the Wireless device is still not working.

From `lscpci`

```
$ lspci -nn -d 168c:0032
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. Device [168c:0032] (rev 01)
```

**Update:**

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-compat-wireless-3.3-2.6.32-51-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-backports-modules-compat-wireless-3.3-2.6.32-51-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package linux-backports-modules-compat-wireless-3.3-2.6.32-51-generic has no installation candidate
```

Comment: The driver ath9k is present in 10.04, but may not cover your specific device. Please edit your question to add details of your device from the terminal command: lspci -nn -d 168c:

Comment: Updated the question with the device id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device 168c:0032 is covered in the linux-backports-modules-compat-wireless-**3.3** package. Please open Synaptic package manager and search for the 3.3 package that matches your currently running kernel version; find out with the terminal command:

```
uname -r
```

As an example, if you are running 2.6.32-51-generic, then, in Synaptic, select and install linux-backports-modules-compat-wireless-3.3-2.6.32-51-generic. After it's done, load the module:

```
sudo modprobe ath9k
```

Your wireless should then be working.

Comment: I updated the question after I tried this

Comment: What did 'uname -r' tell us?

Comment: 2.6.32-51-generic-pae

Comment: Then you need linux-backports-modules-compat-wireless-3.3-2.6.32-51-generic-pae.